# Twig template engine not reading object properties

Tags: php, overloading, twig

Twig lets you pass array or object to the template and gives you the same interface to access members for both data structures.
So, for example:

```
$test = array('foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 'bar');
```

Will let you access this in template as `test.foo` and `test.bar`

Now instance of this object will have the same effect. Which is very awesome :)

```
class test
{
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
}
```

How about an object that uses magic __set and __get methods?

```
class test
{
    public $properties;

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->properties[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->properties[$name];
    }
}
```

**Unfortunately in this case you can't access properties of this object.
 I'm not sure if the Twig is the issue here or PHP itself.**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to implement [`__isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) as well, eg

```
public function __isset($name) {
    return array_key_exists($name, $this->properties);
}
```

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#using-dynamic-object-properties

Comment: Ahh thank you! I new there must be some easy solution to this.

Comment: Phil Do you know by any chance how to get a size of iterable object? `obj|length` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @marcin_koss You're best opening another question but at a guess, I would first try implementing [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php)